# PiCamera not Working - not enough resources

Tags: python

[image: error]

I suspected the problem is that another process is hooking to my camera and thus giving me this error. Does anybody have any idea how i can close the other processes? I've tried rebooting, changing my camera, memory split and everything doesn't work. So does anybody knows a way i can reset/release the camera? Thanks.

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: edit the post, include the text of the error, not a picture. And include the ouput of 'df' as well

Answer (score 1):

The error `ENOSPC` usually means that a file system is full. Depending on the file system, it can also mean the the inode table is full, so while there are free block, new files can't be created.